# Can a class loaded with @Inject use an @EJB?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, cdi

**TL;DR:** Web Service uses an `@Inject`ed class, `@Inject`ed class uses `@EJB`s.  `@EJB`s are null.  Why are they null and how do I fix this?

---

I'm using Glassfish 3 and I have a `@Stateless` `@WebService` that is `@Inject`ing a class with a `@Dependent` annotation on it.  I'd like this class to be able to use other stateless ejbs as fields like this:

```
@EJB(name = "ejb/MySessionBean", beanName = "MySessionBean")
private MySessionLocal mySessionLocal;
```

But, when I try to call this web service, these `@EJB` fields are null (although the `@Dependent` class itself seems to be injected into the web service correctly).  Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

I should add that my Web Service and my EJBs are in an EJB jar in an ear's root.  The `@Dependent` class is inside a jar in the ear's lib/ directory.

**UPDATE:** I've discovered that the @EJBs work correctly (are not null) if I move the `@Dependent` class into the same jar as the web service.  To me this suggests a classloader issue?  An ear's ejb jar can `@Inject` a class in a "lib/*.jar", but a class in a "lib/*.jar" can't get an `@EJB` from a ejb jar in the ear's root.

It's still unclear to me if this is by design.

Comment: Have you tried substituting @EJB with @Inject?

Comment: @AdrianMitev It fails on startup.  "WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type web service"

Answer (score 1):

> An ear's ejb jar can `@Inject` a class in a "`lib/*.jar`", but a class in a "`lib/*.jar`" can't get an `@EJB` from a ejb jar in the ear's root.
>
> It's still unclear to me if this is by design.

I believe this is by design.  A library (something in the `.ear` file's library directory) does not have to be processed by the machinery that fills `@EJB`-annotated slots.  To put it another way, only a Java EE module (an EJB jar, a web application) will have its `@EJB`-annotated fields "filled".

CDI, by contrast, has no such restrictions (provided that the relevant `META-INF/beans.xml` files exist), so it can "fill" `@Inject`-annotated fields with beans sourced from any bean archive.

Comment: OK, so what's the solution?  Code in my library calls my EJBs.  Refer to my answer to see how I normally accomplish this.

Comment: Your solution of using JNDI is the only possible one if you wish to use `@EJB` annotations and not `@Inject` and CDI everywhere.  It works because at the time your library makes the call it is within the "`comp/env`" context of an EJB module or a web application.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I wouldn't mind using @Inject everywhere, but as I said on my question's comment, this throws errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, though I'd prefer not to have to use it.  Its always been the case that I can get a reference to the `@EJB` by doing this (in my "lib/*.jar"):

```
//inside EjbLookup.java

public <T> T lookupEjb(String sessionBeanClassName) {
    return lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/" + sessionBeanClassName);
}

public <T> T lookup(String name) {
    try {
        Context c = new InitialContext();
        return (T) c.lookup(name);
    } catch (NamingException ne) {
        log.error(ne.getMessage(), ne);
        throw new RuntimeException(ne);
    }
}
```

So I can create a class like this in my "lib/*.jar":

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

public class EjbProducer {

    private EjbLookup ejbLookup = new EjbLookup();

    @Produces
    public MySessionLocal getMySessionLocal() {
        return ejbLookup.lookupEjb("MySessionBean");
    }

}
```

And now I can `@Inject` the EJB anywhere in my "lib/*.jar" by doing this:

```
@Inject
private MySessionLocal mySessionLocal;
```

On the other hand, if I attempt to use this code inside the EJB jar itself, I get an error about how the stateless ejb could not be created.  Perhaps that has more to do with the way you're supposed to use JNDI than CDI though.  I can work around this by using `@EJB` when I'm inside the ejb jar and using `@Inject` when I'm in the lib.